# Require_once() and include_once() fails

Tags: php

I've no any problem while I use require_once() or include_once() in the same directory. But if I use like below:

I have a php class page name **email.class.php** where I have included the below code.

```
<?php
require_once('../../configuration.php'); //The file is outside of directory. (root/system/class/) where the configuration.php file is not in the class directory but in root directory
?>
```

now I have a **subscription form where the email.class.php is included** like below.

```
<?php
require_once('../class/email.class.php'); // Directory structure is like: (root/system/package/) // the formprocess.php is in the package folder.
?>
```

It seems everything correct. but when I try to process a form, a **Fatal Error:** require_once fail to open required ../../configuration.php file something shows.
Then i tried to use URL instead of **'../..configuration.php'**. But my host not allows me to open URL. where is the problem ? please help me anyone. I'm just a learner.

Comment: See `getcwd()` and `realpath()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use full path like `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../configuration.php');`

Or `require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../configuration.php')` if you php version >= 5.3

Comment: Thank you, This solution works perfectly for me. I have a small question? why you used **dirname(__FILE__).'/** <--- the trailing slash ('/' before '../'). means why you wrote '/../../configuration.php insted of '../../configuration.php'. I'm unaware about it.

Comment: because `dirname(__FILE__)` will not give you the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

possible reasons:

- you dont allow you webserver to access that specific directory
- the directory path is wrong (style: .. for folder-out /foldername for in-folder depending on the current processing location

check the help for more infos.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php